# Flowchart else if

Tags: flowchart

I'm making a flowchart a for an algorithm, and came into some problem for an else if statement.

For an if-statement such as this one

```
if (something) {}
else if (something) {}
else {}
```

How would the else if statement look like in a flowchart diagram?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

http://code2flow.com allows you to create such flowcharts from code.

[image]

You may click to edit this.

Comment: Thank you - I have been looking for a tool like this and it will be really useful.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the [DRAKON](http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/DRAKON.pdf) version of this:

```
if (case1) {outcome1}
else if (case2) {outcome2}
else {outcome3}
```

[image: if and else if in DRAKON]

Alternatively, it could look like this:

[image: switch construct in DRAKON]

See here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON

Comment: Superb .. very helpful +1

Comment: second one useful only if condition (case 1,case 2) are relevant. so it become switch case.

Answer (score 1):

You could diagram this as two separate if statements.

I don't know if this is the "standard" method, but that's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, let's recast the statement.

```
if (case1) {outcome1}
else if (case2) {outcome2}
else {outcome3}
```

Does it not flow thus?

case1? yes --> outcome1

no --> case2? yes --> outcome2

no --> outcome3