# How would you present this code in a flowchart diagram?

Tags: diagram, flowchart

I'm having trouble to represent something in a flow chart diagram as I'm not sure how to display the following condition other then with plenty of repetition.

```
if(condition1 || condition2 || condition3){
 //Throw event
 //Exit process
}
//contiune process
```

Comment: Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19243081/5811973).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flowchart else if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718619/flowchart-else-if)